# Set image from bitmap

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
Image image = new Image ();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap (200, 100, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

var paint = new Paint();
paint.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.Red;
paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);

Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 200, 100);
canvas.DrawRect(rect, paint);
```

*Android.Widget.ImageView* contains **method SetImageBitmap**.
What the best way to set *Xamarin.Forms.Image* from my bitmap?

Answer (score 2):

Convert the `Bitmap` to `byte[]` via http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5950/how-to-convert-from-bitmap-to-byte-without-bitmap-compress

There are two solutions mentioned.

1. ```
   var byteArray = ByteBuffer.Allocate(bitmap.ByteCount);
   bitmap.CopyPixelsToBuffer(byteArray);
   byte[] bytes = byteArray.ToArray<byte>();
   return bytes;
   ```
2. (in case first solution is still broken)

   ```
   ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.Allocate(bitmap.ByteCount);
   bitmap.CopyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
   buffer.Rewind();

   IntPtr classHandle = JNIEnv.FindClass("java/nio/ByteBuffer");
   IntPtr methodId = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(classHandle, "array", "()[B");
   IntPtr resultHandle = JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod(buffer.Handle, methodId);
   byte[] byteArray = JNIEnv.GetArray<byte>(resultHandle);
   JNIEnv.DeleteLocalRef(resultHandle);
   ```

And then use

```
var image = new Image();
image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(byteArray));
```

to create an `Image`.

Comment: @Kirill Don't pass the stream itself. Pass a method that creates the stream. See changes in the last line of code in the answer.

Comment: 1st solution have exception, 2nd solution - image.Width == -1 (doesn't work too)

Answer (score 0):

I tried @Wosi's answer, but for some reason the rendering of the image after that didn't work and the code is specific to Android. I needed to work from a byte array to a bitmap and then back again. This is what I did:

Code for turning a bitmap into a byte array:

```
        byte[] bitmapData;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            tempBitmap.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
            bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
        }
```

And the code for turning a byte array into a bitmap:

```
 Android.Graphics.Bitmap tempBitmap = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageByteArray, 0, imageByteArray.Length, options);
```

Where "**options**" is defined as follows:

```
        Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.Options options = new Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.Options
        {
            InJustDecodeBounds = true
        };
        Android.Graphics.Bitmap result = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(bitmapArray, 0, byteArrayLength, options);
        //int imageHeight = options.OutHeight;
        //int imageWidth = options.OutWidth;
```

In this part the Bitmap gets decoded. This is done to get the image height and width properties. For my case I required this information to encode it as a byte array again.

There with this it is possible to encode a byte array to a string and then back again.

Setting an image source from a byte array is done as follows:

```
var imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(ImageByteArray, 0, ImageByteArray.Length));
```